# Does JavaScript recreates functions which are after return

Tags: javascript

Following code:

```
a = function(b) {

    return alfa() + b;

    function alfa() {
        return 7;
    }
}

console.log(a(4));
console.log(a(5));
```

Does function alfa() is created on each call to a()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

The syntax you use is sugar for this :

```
a = function(b) {
    var alfa = function() {
            return 7;
    }
    return alfa() + b;
}

console.log(a(4));
console.log(a(5));
```

It makes it clearer you're creating and assigning `alfa` each time you execute `a`.

You could also test it with this simple change :

```
a = function(b) {
    return alfa; // let's return the function
    function alfa() {
            return 7;
    }
}
console.log(a(4)==a(4)); // logs false
```

If you want to avoid `alfa` to be created each time, you may do this :

```
a = (function(){
  var alfa = function() {
     return 7;
  }
  return function(b) {
     return alfa() + b; 
  }
})();
```

Comment: "syntactic sugar" means that you have another syntax for the same effect. Your example doesn't have the same effect, and thus is not syntactic sugar. But it's a nice analogy :P

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Why it doesn't have same effect?

Comment: @FlorianMargaine is right. In this case, a new *variable* is declared which gets a *function expression* assigned as reference. We are no longer talking about a *function declaration* here. I'm not saying that will change anything at run-time, but still, its a big difference under the hood.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it will.

*Function declarations* and variables declared by `var` are both *hoisted up* on function invocation. That means, regardless *where* in a function context, a *function declaration* is declared, it will technically always be up-front.

```
a = function(b) {
    return alfa() + b;

    function alfa() {
        return 7;
    }
}
```

will technically become

```
a = function(b) {
    function alfa() {
        return 7;
    }

    return alfa() + b;
}
```

Comment: The question has nothing to do with hoisting.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I'm uncertain. The last question about the *initialization* of the function, pretty much has.

Comment: You mean "Does function alfa() is created on each call to a()?"* How does that relate to hoisting?

Comment: I don't get your point here. The whole question seems to me like the OP is confused about the `return` statement and a later *function declarations*. How can that issue not be around hoisting of such ?

Comment: Wow, we just *totally* read "Does function get created on each call to a()" differently. I don't see anything like "Why can I call `alfa` before I've defined it?" I see "...on each call to a()" and just see zero about the order of things. But no worries.

Answer (score 2):

> Does function alfa() is created on each call to a()?

A new function *object* is created every time, yes, and binds to a different execution context (so it has access to the value of `b` that was passed into `a` when it was created; `alfa` is a "closure" over the context of the call to `a` in which it was created).

A smart JavaScript engine (like V8) may well reuse the underlying *code*, but a different object is created each time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will. Every time you call `a`, a new instance of `alfa` will be created.

By the way, in this case, `alfa` *closes over* the `a` context. This is what we call a *closure*, and allows us to hold state in a function between different calls.

Comment: Except that `alpha()` is only run once and then destroyed.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `In computer programming, a scope is the context within a computer program in which a variable name or other identifier is valid and can be used`

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: Right. And closures aren't about scope, they're about access to the execution context created by the call to `a`. Scope is about symbol resolution. Put another way: All calls to `a` have the same scope (set of variable names available to them), but each call to `a` has its own execution context (specific *instances* of those variables), which is what makes closures useful. (BTW, if you're going to quote something, shouldn't you cite it? Or if it's original text, why make it look like a quote?) :-)

Comment: @Jack: True, but in theory it's still a closure during the brief time it exists. (In the real world, it probably never exists, since any half-decent engine will inline it, but...)

Comment: ..its actually more a lexical lookup of all *parent-context activation objects* respectively *lexical environment records*, which both are stored within the *execution context*.

Comment: @jAndy: I was avoiding introducing the worst of the spec-speak.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I see :) However, I find it rather important to bring the world *lexical* at all costs at least, because it makes things easier to understand (in my mind). Especially that *lexical scope* expression thing..

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry, the quote comes from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)). I thought an execution context was a scope, thus a new scope is created every time `a` is created. I'd need a real source to validate that you're wrong :P

Comment: I think in lexical scope, the variable is bound to a new variable every time. Thus, a new lexical scope is created every time. The scope in a generic sense is unique though. Is that it?

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: If you want the full skinny, read [§10](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10) of the spec. Brace yourself, though, for some of the most turgid prose you've ever read. Scope is a lexical concept (the textual nesting of things). The execution context is a runtime concept. It's the intersection of these (via the binding objects associated with the chain of execution contexts) that defines the values a closure sees. Anyway, enjoy! ;-) (Apropos of nothing, btw, always glad to see you answering questions. A definite cut above. You and jAndy both, actually.)

Comment: Ah, thank! I'll take some time to read that. I'm getting used to it... (Thanks for the compliment btw, I appreciate.)